# Splitting set $S$ of size $n$ into two disjoint subsets

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, probabilistic-method

> Let $S$ be a set of size $n$. For any $N$ subsets of $S$ of size $m$, if
>   $$N<2^{m-1}\,,$$
>   then prove that there exists a way to split $S$ into two disjoint subsets $A$ and $B$ (with $A\cup B=S$) such that none of the smaller $N$ subsets are subsets of either $A$ or $B$.

I have been trying to do this question for hours, but have gotten nowhere closer to the solution. Any hints as to how to begin this would be appreciated.

Comment: is it a deterministic or probabilitic statement ? (you start with random choices, but your conclusion is deterministic...)

Comment: @Olivier Oh yeah thanks I worded it badly. I'm trying to say that for any N subsets of size m we can find disjoint subsets A and B which satisfy the conditions. I will edit the question

Comment: Why the probability tag? Is this problem from a course where you're learning to use the probabilistic method? Now that's a hint. How about you take each element of $S$ in turn and flip a coin to decide whether to put it in $A$ or $B$? Let $p$ be the probability that the resulting partition fails to have the property you want. Now if only you could prove that $p\lt1$ . . .

Comment: @bof yeah the question is asking to use probabilistic method, but I wasn't sure how to do that. I will try thinking about the question your way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $S_i$ for $i=1,2,\ldots,N$ denote the $N$ given subsets of $S$.  Suppose that $X$ is a subset of $S$ uniformly randomly chosen from all the $2^n$ subsets of $S$.  Define $Y(X):=S\setminus X$.

For a fixed value $i\in\{1,2,\ldots,N\}$, the probability that $S_i\subseteq X$ is $\dfrac{2^{n-m}}{2^n}=\dfrac{1}{2^{m}}$ (because $|S_i|=m$ and $X\setminus S_i$ is a random subset of $S\setminus S_i$).  Similarly, the probability that $S_i\subseteq Y(X)$ is $\dfrac{1}{2^m}$.  Therefore, the probability $p_i$ that $S_i\subseteq X$ or $S_i\subseteq Y(X)$ is 
$$p_i\leq \frac{1}{2^{m}}+\frac{1}{2^{m}}=\frac{1}{2^{m-1}}\,.$$
(For a positive integer $m$, $p_i=\dfrac1{2^{m-1}}$, but I just want to include the trivial case $m=0$.  The OP has never said that $m$ has to be a positive integer.)

Since $N<2^{m-1}$, we obtain
$$\sum_{i=1}^N\,p_i\leq \frac{N}{2^{m-1}}<1\,.$$
However, the probability that $S_i\subseteq X$ or $S_i\subseteq Y(X)$ for some $i\in\{1,2,\ldots,N\}$ is at most $\sum\limits_{i=1}^N\,p_i$ (due to subadditivity of probability measures).  Consequently, the probability that $S_i\subseteq X$ or $S_i\subseteq Y(X)$ for no $i\in\{1,2,\ldots,N\}$ is at least $$1-\sum\limits_{i=1}^N\,p_i>0\,.$$ Ergo, there exists $A\subseteq S$ such that there are no $i\in \{1,2,\ldots,N\}$ for which $S_i\subseteq A$ or $S_i\subseteq Y(A)=:B$.

Comment: If we assume $m\ge2$ (losing some trivial cases) then I think the assumption $N\lt2^{m-1}$ can be weakened to $N\le2^{m-1}$.